# Cells not deleting from both tableviews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have some items in one tableview shown like so...

[image]

If the `Add To Cart` button is clicked, then that particular data in cell is shown in another view like so..

[image]

But in the `products` view if I click on the remove button of the product named `fgh` then it should disappear from the cart view(the 2nd image). But when I click on the `remove` button, nothing happens and the product named `fgh` still persists in the cart view. This is the code on the click of remove button...

```
func removeBtnTapped(cell: ProductListFrCartViewControllerTableViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = tableview?.indexPath(for: cell) {

    let context1 = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request: NSFetchRequest<CartProducts> = CartProducts.fetchRequest()

    let sdf1 = newProdDetails[indexPath.row]
    let dfg2 = sdf1.productID

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "productID == %@", dfg2!)
                request.predicate = predicate
                request.fetchLimit = 1

    if let result = try? context1.fetch(request) {
          for object in result {

              let sdf = cartDetails.index(of: object)
                        context1.delete(object)
                        self.cartDetails.remove(at: sdf!)
        }
    }
    do {                
        try context1.save()
    } catch { }
    tableview.reloadData()
}
```

I basically want to remove from the cart view that product which has same id as that of the product(whose remove button is clicked) in products view. This could solve the issue but I'm not sure how to achieve it...

Comment: Why do you use a repeat loop `for object in result` although the fetch limit is 1? And rather than `reload`ing the entire table view use `deleteRows` to get a nice animation.

Comment: ok..so how can I access the individual element in my array without the loop..? anyways what I did above isn't working so I'm not sure if this is the issue or something else is causing the problem...

Comment: This does not the cause the issue. Put the fetch line in the `do` block and write `if let object = try context1.fetch(request).first { let sdf = cartDetails.index(of: object) ...`. And put at least a `print(error)` in the `catch` scope. Ignoring errors is pretty bad habit.

Comment: sure @vadian..I'll just try...Thanks

Comment: To solve the issue: did you remove the object in the other data source and reload the table view, too? Maybe it's worth it to use a `FetchedResultsController` which handles the UI update.

Comment: actually..when I delete an item from a particular coredata array, I load the same array when I go to the other view. So the changes are reflected there also...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164170/discussion-between-bvt-and-vadian).